# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'try'

Tags: javascript

Я изучаю JS по интерактивному учебнику. Сейчас я на этой главе: https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html
(В этом учебнике открывается редактор, если нажать на код. Запустить код можно нажатием Ctrl+Enter).
Делаю второе упражнение (Groups, в конце главы), и встретилась с ошибкой, текст которой даже не сообщает, какая строка её вызывает:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'try'
```

Вот мой код:

```js
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.content = [];
  }

  add(element) {
    if (!this.content.includes(element)) {
        this.content.push(element);
    }
  }

  delete(element) {
    this.content.splice(this.content.indexOf(element), 1);
  }

  has(element) {
    return this.content.indexOf(element) >= 0;
  }

  static from(iterableObject) {
    let newGroup = new Group();
    for (let element of iterableObject) {
      newGroup.add(element);
    }
    return newGroup;
  }
};

let group = Group.from([10, 20]);
console.log(group.has(10));
// → true
console.log(group.has(30));
// → false
group.add(10);
group.delete(10);
console.log(group.has(10));
// → false
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что вызывает ошибку, и как её исправить.

Comment: Код полностью рабочий. Скорее всего, проблема в исполнителе кода в учебнике

Comment: @АлександрЛесив Благодарю. В предыдущих учебниках ошибок не возникало, так что я была уверена, что проблема в моем коде.

Comment: @АлександрЛесив *в предыдущих упражнениях